# Error after upgrading from v5.22.0 to v5.29.1 in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I have a WordPress website that is using v5.22.0 of CiviCRM, it was a fresh install and this is my first time trying to upgrade it.

To upgrade to v5.29.1 I followed all steps to the letter:
https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/

When I attempt the final step to upgrade the database which is to point your browser to the URL http://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1 (obviously replacing example.org with our domain) I get the error message and there is no Upgrade Now button:

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
> moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
> with more details about what action you were performing when this
> occurred. Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM 5.22.0

Am I done? Is there no database upgrade to be done between v5.22.0 and v5.29.1? Everything appears to be working on the front / backend.... did I do it properly?

Comment: It looks like it's not picking up the new code base - there is always an upgrade- you don't still have the old code 'somewhere' on you system do you? There should be a file in your civi dir xml/version.xml with the version....

Comment: Found a copy of the old codebase! Got rid of that and working now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding an answer - which is actually from the comments - since I think stackexchange doesn't like answers in the comments - anyway - the issue was an extra copy of the codebase